# Access Sibling Windows after Parent closes

Tags: javascript, html

I am currenlty developing a webapp in which I would like children windows of a parent to be able to communicate with each other. The reason I want the siblings to communicate is because there is no guarantee that the parent will stay opened, as the parent is iFramed into Microsoft CRM, and the parent will close if they change their tab (if this weren't the case I would just have the parent handle the communication).

The following works in Chrome but not IE, and I'm wondering if there is another way that it could be done.

In Parent window:

```
var children = new Array();
function openWindow(...){
  children.push(window.open(...));
}
```

In Child Window:

```
var siblings = window.opener.children;
```

Then if the parent window closes, this line still works in chrome but not IE

```
siblings[0].close();
```

I haven't tried anything other than close yet, but I believe that all functions should be accessable (as they're in the same domain). The fact that it worked in Chrome was a pleasant surprise to me, but we do need to support IE as well

**EDIT**

One method that just came to mind would be that when the parent closes to change the parent of the children to one of the other children (IE parent re-assigns parent to be a child window). But I'm not sure if this would be valid or even possible because I feel like it would still make the references disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I whipped something up to try and test this out because I hadn't ever heard of it before.  However,  it works pretty well.  I have a parent window that keeps track of the windows that it spawns in an array.  Then whenever it spawns a new window it tells the children about their new brother/sister so that **they** can keep track of him as well.  Then each child has their own method that lets them receive messages from their siblings.  I also gave them simple inputs to be able to message each other and print out the messages that they receive.

**`Edit`**

Ok, did a full rewrite of the code to be more robust and so that you didn't have to explicitly tell the children about each other manually.  Now, the parent has hooked events for whenever it is `loaded` and `unloaded` so that it can tell it's children that it won't be there any more.  That doesn't really matter as the children are notified of each other's existences as they are created.  The only thing that is a bit tricky is if you were to create more windows after the parent gets closed.

The parent coordinates the children through the `ParentModule.spawnChild()` function.  That's what lets children know about new children.  So if you want to make new windows after the parent closes, you'll have to tweak some functions.  However, here is the code for intercommunication between a parent and child windows even after the parent closes.  Do keep in mind, this relies on `same-origin policy`.

Also, added a way to let the parent know when their child is closed.

---

**Parent**

*parent.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Parent</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style></style>
      <script src="parent.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="main();" onunload="ParentModule.notifyChildren();">
      <button id="closer">Close</button>
      <div>New Child's Name</div>
      <input type="text" id="newChildName">
      <button id="spawner">Spawn Child</button>
      <div id="log"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

*parent.js*

```
/**
 * The namespace for the parent window
 * @namespace ParentModule
 */
var ParentModule = (function() {
   // Create an object to keep functions we want to be public
   var exports = {};

   /**
    * The children windows
    * @type Object
    */
   exports.childWindows = {};

   /**
    * The number of children we have
    * @type Number
    */
   exports.numChildren = 0;

   /**
    * Create a new window and keep other windows in sync with the event
    * @param {String} childName The name of the new child
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.spawnChild = function(childName) {
      // Create a new window
      var newChild = window.open(
              "child.html",
              childName,
              "height=200, width=200, top=200, left=" + (200 * exports.numChildren)),
              parent = window;

      // Whenever the new window is finished loading, tell the window its
      // name, its parent, and its siblings.  Then tell the other children
      // about their new siblings as well so that they can message him
      // and mourn him if he gets closed.
      newChild.addEventListener("load", function() {

         // Log that the child was made
         document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "New child: " + childName;

         // Tell the child its name
         newChild.ChildModule.giveName(childName);

         // Tell the child its parent
         newChild.ChildModule.setParent(parent);

         // Tell new child about its siblings
         for (var child in exports.childWindows) {
            newChild.ChildModule.addSibling(exports.childWindows[child], child);
         }

         // Tell all children about the new child
         for (var child in exports.childWindows) {
            exports.childWindows[child].ChildModule.addSibling(newChild, childName);
         }

         // Keep track of the new child yourself
         exports.childWindows[childName] = newChild;

         // Tell the child to say hi
         newChild.ChildModule.start();
      });
   };

   /**
    * Function called whenever a child is closed
    * @param {String} childName Child that is getting closed
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.removeChild = function(childName) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      log.innerHTML = "My child: " + childName + " is gone";
      delete exports.childWindows[childName];
   };

   /**
    * Let all children know that you are being closed
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.notifyChildren = function() {
      for (var child in exports.childWindows) {
         exports.childWindows[child].ChildModule.removeParent();
      }
   };

   /**
    * Shortcut to be able to close all children
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.closeAllChildren = function() {
      for (var child in exports.childWindows) {
         exports.childWindows[child].close();
      }
   };

   // Allow functions to get called
   return exports;
}());

/**
 * Function to setup the listeners
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function main() {
   document.getElementById("spawner").addEventListener("click", function() {
      ParentModule.spawnChild(document.getElementById("newChildName").value);
   });
   document.getElementById("closer").addEventListener("click", function() {
      ParentModule.closeAllChildren();
   });
}
```

---

**Child**

*child.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Child</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style></style>
      <script src="child.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body onload="main();" onunload="ChildModule.notifyKinOfDeath();">
      <div>Destination Window</div>
      <input type="text" id="whichWin">
      <div>Message</div>
      <input type="text" id="message">
      <button id="sendMessage">Send Window a Message</button>
      <div id="myName">I'm a child</div>
      <div id="log"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

*child.js*

```
/**
 * The namespace for the child window's functions
 * @namespace ChildModule
 */
var ChildModule = (function() {
   // Create an object to keep functions we want to be public
   var exports = {};

   /**
    * The other siblings that this window should know about
    * @type Object
    */
   exports.siblingWindows = {};

   /**
    * This child's name
    * @type String
    */
   exports.name = "";

   /**
    * This child's parent
    * @type Window
    */
   exports.parent = null;

   /**
    * This function is written from the perspective of another window
    * This is the way that another window can send THIS window a message
    * @param {String} envelope Message for the child to get
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.sendMessage = function(envelope) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      log.innerHTML = "Got: " + envelope.message + " from: " + envelope.sender;
   };

   /**
    * This is written from the child's perspective
    * This will actually send the message to the target sibling
    * @param {String} targetSibling The sibling to message
    * @param {String} message The message to send
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.passMessage = function(targetSibling, message) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      if (exports.siblingWindows[targetSibling]) {
         exports.siblingWindows[targetSibling].ChildModule.sendMessage({
            "sender": exports.name,
            "message": message
         });
      }
      else {
         log.innerHTML = "I have no sibling: " + targetSibling;
      }
   };

   /**
    * This function is written from the perspective of another window
    * Give this child its name
    * @param {type} name
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.giveName = function(name) {
      exports.name = name;
      document.getElementById("myName").innerHTML = "My name is: " + exports.name;
   };

   /**
    * Function to get the child's name
    * @returns {String}
    */
   exports.getName = function() {
      return exports.name;
   };

   /**
    * Set the parent of this window
    * @param {Window} parent The window that spawned this child
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.setParent = function(parent) {
      exports.parent = parent;
   };

   /**
    * What this child should do once started
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.start = function() {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      log.innerHTML = "Hello, my name is: " + exports.name;
   };

   /**
    * Understand that a we have a new sibling that we can message
    * @param {Window} sibling The new sibling
    * @param {String} siblingName The name of the new sibling
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.addSibling = function(sibling, siblingName) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      exports.siblingWindows[siblingName] = sibling;
      log.innerHTML = "I have a brother named: " + siblingName;
   };

   /**
    * Understand that a sibling has left us so we can't message them
    * @param {String} siblingName Name of sibling that is gone
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.removeSibling = function(siblingName) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      log.innerHTML = "My brother: " + siblingName + " is gone";
      delete exports.siblingWindows[siblingName];
   };

   /**
    * Understand that the parent has been closed
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.removeParent = function() {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      exports.parent = null;
      log.innerHTML = "My parent is gone";
   };

   /**
    * Whenever a child is unloaded, notify everyone of its death
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   exports.notifyKinOfDeath = function() {
      // Tell parent of your closing
      if (exports.parent) {
         exports.parent.ParentModule.removeChild(exports.name);
      }

      // Tell siblings of your closing
      for (var sibling in exports.siblingWindows) {
         exports.siblingWindows[sibling].ChildModule.removeSibling(exports.name);
         console.log("I've told them");
      }
   };

   // Allow functions to get called
   return exports;
}());

/**
 * Function to setup listeners
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function main() {
   document.getElementById("sendMessage").addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Get the message and the window to send to
      var whichWin = document.getElementById("whichWin").value,
              messageToSend = document.getElementById("message").value;

      // Send the message
      ChildModule.passMessage(whichWin, messageToSend);
   });
}
```

Comment: Well, I ended up solving this by just using session storage, but i do want to give you credit for answering the question (very thoroughly). I seem to be having issues in Chrome though. The close button just makes my Chrome window unresponsive. I also am running into issues with each sibling saying that it has no sibling and the message not being sent